# Qgis mapserver - Can it use plugins you use in qgis desktop?

Tags: qgis, python, postgis, qgis-server

Im thinking about developing a small python plugin for qgis which would access postgis raster database and return data via ST_AsPNG() for example. But since i need this in my wms, would it be possible for mapserver executable to also use this plugin, because the plugin would be used in the project file to fetch the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understand the question, anyway the next qgis release will support macros (python) in projects, so probably this would help do what you need.

Comment: From the qgi server executable perspective: It reads the project file, iterates through ToC and renders according to the styling/path instructions in the project file. But what if something was added into the ToC which needs some python plugin to work which you of course can use in desktop qgis, but server probably isnt aware of that?